# Adding entry of one dataset into another dataset

Tags: matlab, dataset

What i have is two datasets one containing name and income and the other containing name only.Dataset2 is a subset of Dataset1. I want to fill the 2nd column of Dataset2(which is income) by copying it from Dataset1 (the respective income of a person).

Example:

```
    Dataset1
```

Name          Income

1.martin         500
2.alex           200
3.sam            400
4.nikita         300

```
   Dataset2
```

Name
1.martin
2.sam

```
  Result
```

Name         Income

1.martin     500
2.sam        400

Comment: What did you try so far? Take a look at `strfind`

Comment: How can you do it by strfind? I have about 15000 rows, how can i specify pattern for strfind.

Comment: You are right, I wrote the wrong function name. `strcmpi` allows to search a cell for a specific string. First input is the name you are searching, second a cell of all names.

Comment: By using strcmpi, i will get the index in dataset1,but i don't want to modify dataset1. I want to fill the corresponding entries in dataset2. How should i do that.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the used data structures. Each is a cell array?

Comment: I can store it as cell array.

Answer (score 1):

Create a second column in Dataset 2:

```
Dataset2(:,2)={0}
```

Search for the right data and fill column 2 in `Dataset2`

```
%call for each line in a loop:
Dataset2{line,2}=Dataset1{find(strcmpi(Dataset2{line,1},Dataset1(:,1))),2}
```